# Possible error on /search/excerpts documentation?

Tags: support, bug, api, documentation

The StackExchange API documentation states the following for the tagged parameter of [/search/excerpts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search):

> tagged - a semicolon delimited list of tags, of which **at least one**
> will be present on all returned questions.

In other words, the semicolon works as an OR operator. However, during some tests, I found that the semicolon
works in reality as an AND operator. For example, the API call

[/2.2/search/excerpts?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=fortran;blockchain&site=stackoverflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=fortran;blockchain&site=stackoverflow)

returns an empty list though there are several questions that have only fortran as a tag or that have only
blockchain as a tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed an error.

The correct text should be:

> tagged - a **ampersand** delimited list of tags, of which at least one will be present on all returned questions.

To prove this, both of these queries give the same result:

- https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=fortran&blockchain&site=stackoverflow
- https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/excerpts?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=fortran&site=stackoverflow